# Laravel, how to use form helper outside blade?

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-4, form-helpers

For some reason I have to write HTML::macro() to return HTML tags.

```
HTML::macro('myMycro', function()
{
  $result = '<form id="xxx">...';
  return = $result;
}
```

then I can use the HTML::myMacro() inside my blade.

```
{{ HTML::myMacro() }}
```

Is it possible to use form helper Form::open(), Form::input() to generate HTML tags inside the macro so I don't have to manually write  tags???

If so, please suggest me how to do it because of my poor background in PHP and Laravel, I just simply tried

```
...
$result = Form::open('some_parameters'); 
...
```

But I didn't work, I don't know can I use form helper outside blade or not, so please advise me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I dont see any reason why not.
This works like a charm

```
Form::macro('myForm', function()
{
    $output = Form::open(['url/to/post']);
    $output .= Form::text('firstName');
    $output .= Form::close();
        return $output;
});

// Then use in in regular PHP view...
echo Form::myForm();

// ... or even Blade view
{{ Form::myForm() }}
```